# Scraping data in Excel format from URL into R

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to download data from url
https://migration.iom.int/datasets/europe-%E2%80%94-mixed-migration-flows-europe-quarterly-overview-april-june-2021

On this page is available dataset with file into Excel and link for downloading data is https://migration.iom.int/system/tdf/datasets/Q2%202021%20Mixed%20Migration%20Flows%20to%20Europe%20%28April%20-%20June%202021%29.xlsx?file=1&type=node&id=12261

[image]

So I want to download all this data in Excel format directly into R.

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "https://migration.iom.int/system/tdf/datasets/Q2%202021%20Mixed%20Migration%20Flows%20to%20Europe%20%28April%20-%20June%202021%29.xlsx?file=1&type=node&id=12261"
pg <- read_html(URL)

html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "download"), "href")
```

But I made some mistake and I don't make download. So can anybody help me how to download this data into R .

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go about it in the following way.
Download the data into a specified destination, read the excel file from that location. An idea would be:

```
download.file(url, destinationFile)
fileInR <- read.table(file = desinationFile,sep = “\t”)
```

However, a simple google search for both (downloading and reading in an excel file in R) should provide you with plenty more options.